# $resource object throwing errors upon $save

Tags: angularjs

My resource object looks like below:

```
.factory('StudentWebService', ['$resource',function($resource){
  return $resource( baseUrl + 'students/:_id', { _id: '@_id'},
  {
    save: { method: 'POST', isArray: true}
  }
}])
```

Now using the resource like below:

```
var studentObj = new StudentWebService();
studentObj.name = 'john';
studentObj.age = '12';

studentObj.$save()
          .then(function(res) { console.log('i never get called'); })
```

When the above code is executed the save function works i.e the data gets saved on the server, HOWEVER the callback function in the ".then" does not get called and the console shows the following errors:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://xxx/angular.js?version=1411563643:21994:25
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://xxx/angular.js?version=1411563643:323:11)
    at angular.module.factory.Resource.(anonymous function).$http.then.value.$resolved (http://xxx/angular.js?version=1411563643:21993:17)
```

When I visit the line 21994 in angular.js .. thsi is what i see:

```
    if (data) {
      // Need to convert action.isArray to boolean in case it is undefined
      // jshint -W018
      if (angular.isArray(data) !== (!!action.isArray)) {
        throw $resourceMinErr('badcfg', 'Error in resource configuration. Expected ' +
          'response to contain an {0} but got an {1}',
          action.isArray?'array':'object', angular.isArray(data)?'array':'object');
      }
      // jshint +W018
      if (action.isArray) {
        value.length = 0;
        forEach(data, function(item) {
          value.push(new Resource(item));   //THIS IS LINE 21994
        });
      } else {
        shallowClearAndCopy(data, value);
        value.$promise = promise;
      }
    }
```

As a response, the server returns a Array.

EDIT: Few more things to note. when the server returns an Object and there is no isArray defined. the above code works fine.

Can someone point in the right direction as to what I am missing ???

(Do note I have already found a workaround for the time being but I would like to understand the issue here. This is my workaround:

```
    var studentObj = {};
    studentObj.name = 'john';
    studentObj.age = '12';

  StudentWebService.save(studentObj,function(res){
     //this call gets called and works fine
  });
```

Comment: have you tried studentObj.save()?

Comment: yes.. I get the error: undefined is not a function .. it doesnt' recognize save as a function available on studentObj.